# passing variables in query string

Tags: php, query-string

```
$courses_taken=$row['course_id'];
<a href="course.php?course_id=$courses_taken"></a>
```

As you can see from above code, i'm taking a variable and passing it in query string, but this method is wrong.

How can i pass a variable in query string, as each user will have opted for different courses, thus they will have different course_id.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $courses_taken=$row['course_id'];
?>
<a href="course.php?course_id=<?php echo $courses_taken; ?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `echo` statement, and then interpolate the variable inside the string.

```
$courses_taken = $row['course_id'];
echo "<a href='course.php?course_id=$courses_taken'>click here</a>";
```

Comment: I'm sure this works, but another answers is more suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
You are not using php tag to pass php variable in your anchor tag.

Do it like this:

<a href="course.php?course_id=<?= $courses_taken; ?>"></a>
```

-
Thanks

Comment: He's using the "short open tags" feature. `<?=` is short for `<?php echo`

Comment: Yes use either of method. Both are ok with this.