# How to pass values to another php

Tags: php

```
<?php
        $sql="select * from $dbname.product_details";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if (! $result) {
            # code...
            die("invalid query to server");
        }
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            # code...
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                # code...
                echo "**<big><b><a href='productpage.php'>".$row["pdt_name"]."</a></b></big><br><br>**";
                echo "<small>".$row["pdt_description"]."</small><br><br>";
                echo "<big>for only ".$row["pdt_price"]."</big><br>";
                $path="/img/".$row["pdt_id"].".JPG";
                echo "<img src='$path' height='150' width='90' align='center'><br>";
                echo "<hr><br><br>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

This is a part of my PHP code. Each product detail is displayed. The hyperlink, on clicking each product's name, the productdetail.php script should run. Problem now is, how do I pass the product id to the script?

Comment: You need to pass `product id` in your URL.`<a href='productpage.php?product_id=your product id'>Product Name</a>`

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: using query string you pass the product id. refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556627/passing-variables-in-query-string

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this:

```
<?php
    $sql    = "select * from $dbname.product_details";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (! $result) {
        # code...
        die("invalid query to server");
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        # code...
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            # code...
            // POSSIBLY ADD THE PRODUCT-ID TO THE LINK LIKE SO:
            echo "**<big><b><a href='productpage.php?id=" . $row["pdt_id"] . "'>".$row["pdt_name"]."</a></b></big><br><br>**";
            echo "<small>".$row["pdt_description"]."</small><br><br>";
            echo "<big>for only ".$row["pdt_price"]."</big><br>";
            $path="/img/".$row["pdt_id"].".JPG";
            echo "<img src='$path' height='150' width='90' align='center'><br>";
            echo "<hr><br><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

And then inside the productpage.php, you can deal with the ID like so

```
<?php
/**
 * productpage.php
 *
 */
$pdt_id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['id'])) : null;
//NOW YOU CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WILL WITH YOUR $pdt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
<?php
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                # code...
                echo "**<big><b><a href='productpage.php?id='".$row["pdt_id"]."'>".$row["pdt_name"]."</a></b></big><br><br>**";
                echo "<small>".$row["pdt_description"]."</small><br><br>";
                echo "<big>for only ".$row["pdt_price"]."</big><br>";
                $path="/img/".$row["pdt_id"].".JPG";
                echo "<img src='$path' height='150' width='90' align='center'><br>";
                echo "<hr><br><br>";
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following easy step.We use the (.)dot operator for concatinating values in php.Moreover you can notice that the string parts are inside the double quotes where as the $row variable is not inside quotes .Rather it is joined by dot operator on its both sides.

```
<a href="productpage.php?id=".$row['pdt_id']."your rest link part"></a>
```